# using formula notation inside a for loop

Tags: r, r-caret, one-hot-encoding

I have a large dataframe with many factor class features that I am attempting to one hot encode.  I'm attempting to use the dummyVars function from the caret package to do this.  My issue is that since I have a large dataframe, I cannot OHE all of them at once.  Here is the solution that I have come up with:

```
fac <- data.frame()
for (i in names(train.fact)) {
dmy <- dummyVars( ~ i , data = train.fact)
trsf <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = train.fact))
fac <- cbind(fac, trsf)
}
```

My hope is that this for loop would OHE the first feature, store that in fac,  then move onto the next feature, OHE it, and cbind that information to fac and so on.

When attempting to run this, I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , vars, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected
```

I believe this is due to the way the names of each feature are being passed into 'i'.

I also thought this may be done through an apply function but cannot come up with the appropriate syntax.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `as.formula` can turn strings into formulas. Try using that and `paste` to add the `~`.

Comment: I'm not really trying to create a long form formula.  I'm just looking to pass each name in names(train.fact) into the formula one by one.

Comment: Right, so that means you're trying to construct formulas from strings, just like I said. As in, `dummyVars(as.formula(paste("~",i)),...)`.

Comment: I apologize as I didn't realize what your intent was.  This worked as needed.  Thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out!